# How can I install a private Python package on JupyterHub running on a single EC2 instance with multiple users?

Tags: amazon-ec2, jupyter, virtualenv, jupyterhub

I'm trying to create a development environment for a team of data analysts.
The setup should be JupyterHub running on a single EC2 instance with multiple users who have access to a private Python package which I maintain on Github.
Each user should have their own environment with their own notebooks.

I started by installing JupyterHub on an EC2 instance using the installation guide [here](https://tljh.jupyter.org/en/latest/install/amazon.html).

The documentation also mentions that there is a python3 environment which is maintained by the Jupyter service which is located at `/opt/tljh/hub` and that admins can install libraries into this environment, which will be then accessible to all users using this kernel.

I wish to be able to install my own private package (maybe by copying a .whl file into the EC2, or any other way) but I'm not sure how to approach that and given that I make changes to the package source code, how to reflect those changes to the users.